# Div not expanding even with content inside

Tags: css, html

I have a stack of divs inside of each other, all of which have an ID which specifies CSS only.

But for some reason the surrounding DIV tag only expands to it's anointed height value, and not it's default auto, meaning that although the content is inside, the backing DIV is only a specific height. I need it to adjust the heigh to the size of whatever is inside of it (As there will be user submitted data being echoed out possibly in paragraphs with 500+ words.)

```css
#albumhold {
  width: 920px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #E1E1E1;
  background-image: url(../global-images/albumback.png);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#albumpic {
  display: block;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#infohold {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
}

#albumhead {
  width: 800px;
  height: 20px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #09F;
}

#albuminfo {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 800px;
  float: right;
  color: #09F;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="albumhold">
  <div id="albumpic">Pic here</div>
  <div id="infohold">
    <div id="albumhead">Name | Date</div>
    <div id="albuminfo">Information</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 114):

Floated elements don’t take up any vertical space in their containing element.

All of your elements inside `#albumhold` are floated, apart from `#albumhead`, which doesn’t look like it’d take up much space.

However, if you add `overflow: hidden;` to `#albumhold` (or [some other CSS to clear floats inside it](http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/)), it will expand its height to encompass its floated children.

Comment: @Brent: sure, there’s always the clipping to consider. I hadn’t thought about it producing issues with `box-shadow`, that’s a good point.

Answer (score 20):

There are two solutions to fix this:

1. Use `clear:both` after the last floated tag. This works good.
2. If you have fixed height for your div or clipping of content is fine, go with: `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Your solution nr. 1 is a pretty neat fix for this/my issue. Especially while overflow: hidden wouldn´t be an option for me. +1

Answer (score 10):

You probably need a clear fix.

Try this:

[What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 7):

Add `<br style="clear: both" />` after the last floated div worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Putting a `<br clear="all" />` after the last floated div worked the best for me. Thanks to Brent Fiare & Paul Waite for the info that floated divs will not expand the height of the parent div! This has been driving me nuts! ;-}

Answer (score 1):

You have a fixed height on .infohold, so the .albumhold div will only add up to the height of .infohold (20px) + .albumpic (110px) plus any padding or margin which I haven't included there.

Try removing the fixed height on .infohold and see what happens.

Comment: Hmm, so try a clearfix as mentioned by @sym3tri. My favourite is by Dan Cederholm. Add this, and a 'region' class to the albumhold div.
`.clearfix:before, .region:after {
  content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; visibility: hidden; 
} 
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.region { zoom: 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't typed the closingtag  from the div with **id="infohold**.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you don't have a width set anywhere. That was the problem in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35531168)

Answer (score -1):

div will not expand if it has other floating divs inside, so remove the float from the internal divs and it will expand.

Comment: Q:"Why won't my car start?" A:"You should take the bus"